# HTTP update request - how to update only specific fields?

Tags: python, curl, flask

I'm writing in Flask and Python. My update method looks like this:

```
def post(self, medicine_id):
        conn = db_connect.connect()
        last_name = request.json.get('LastName')
        first_name = request.json.get('FirstName')
        title = request.json.get('Title')
        reports_to = request.json.get('ReportsTo')
        birth_date = request.json.get('BirthDate')
        hire_date = request.json.get('HireDate')
        address = request.json.get('Address')
        city = request.json.get('City')
        state = request.json.get('State')
        country = request.json.get('Country')
        postal_code = request.json.get('PostalCode')
        phone = request.json.get('Phone')
        fax = request.json.get('Fax')
        email = request.json.get('Email')
        conn.execute ("UPDATE employees SET LastName='{0}',FirstName='{1}',Title='{2}', \
                      ReportsTo='{3}',BirthDate='{4}',HireDate='{5}',Address='{6}',City='{7}', \
                      State='{8}',Country='{9}',PostalCode='{10}',Phone='{11}',Fax='{12}', \
                      Email='{13}' WHERE EmployeeId={14}".format(last_name, first_name, title,
                                                                 reports_to, birth_date, hire_date,
                                                                 address, city, state, country,
                                                                 postal_code, phone, fax,
                                                                 email, medicine_id))
        return jsonify({"status": "success"})
```

I need to update a specific row in database. I use for that HTTP request which looks like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"City\":\"Lodz\", \"FirstName\":\"Patryk\"}" http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/126
```

In this case, I update a row with ID equals to 126. It updates "City" and "FirstName" column but also it changes other columns with "None". And my question is how should I modify my curl request or Python code just to only update columns specified in curl request. Thanks

Comment: You can update only the fields you actually received from your client (btw, `PATCH` method would better suite this behaviour than `POST`, since `POST` should always create a new item in collection. `PUT` should overwrite it, but some implement the `PATCH`-behaviour on `PUT`). The actual implementation (query construction) depends on which ORM you use.

Comment: Never ever use `.format()` or the `%` string formatting on SQL queries, it will result in SQL injection vulnerability. Use the way documented for the `.execute()` of your DB adapter.

Comment: I use SQLAlchemy ORM..